# Trying to configure SSO for MOODLE

Tags: 14.04, samba, apache2.4, moodle

**EDIT**
I don't actually see the 500 error in the apache2 error log.  I switched moodle's configuration to try NTLM authentication in all browsers, rather than just in IE and the server 500 error no longer appears.  I just need to find out what the issue with the failed authentication is.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache 2.4 and MOODLE 2.6.2, trying to get SSO to work with our Windows domain. I have added the following to the apache2.conf:

```
<IfModule !mod_auth_ntlm_winbind.c>
    LoadModule auth_ntlm_winbind_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_ntlm_winbind.so
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/moodle/auth/ldap/">
    <Files ntlmsso_magic.php>
        NTLMAuth on
        AuthType NTLM
        AuthName "Moodle NTLM Authentication"
        NTLMAuthHelper "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp"
        NTLMBasicAuthoritative on
        require valid-user
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

I also have NTLM turned on in MOODLE, and winbind is installed and working since wbinfo -u and wbinfo -g both return proof that they have bound accounts and groups from the domain controller.

smb.conf has been altered to add the following:

```
[global]

security = ads
realm = mydomain.local
password server = server.mydomain.local
workgroup = mydomain
idmap uid = 10000-20000
idmap gid = 10000-20000
winbind enum users = yes
winbind enum groups = yes
template homedir = /home/%D/%U
template shell = /bin/bash
client use spnego = yes
client ntlmv2 auth = yes
encrypt passwords = yes
winbind use default domain = yes
restrict anonymous = 2
```

When I try to test SSO and log in, I get the message `Auto-login failed, try the normal login window...`

I'm not quite sure which logs to check, as the only evidence I can find in any logs is that there is a 500 internal server error being thrown.

Comment: Just a bump to try to get an answer for this.  I haven't been able to figure this out and have had 0 responses in any location that I have posted this issue.

Comment: Does it look like the same error as this? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache-mod-auth-ntlm-winbind/+bug/1304953

Answer (score 1):

To fix this:

```
usermod -a -G winbindd_priv www-data
chgrp winbindd_priv /var/lib/samba/winbindd_privileged
ln -s /var/lib/samba/winbindd_privileged/pipe /var/run/samba/winbindd_privileged/pipe
```

The Apache module expects the winbindd pipe socket to be found in `/var/run/samba/winbindd_privileged/`. The new location of the file however seems to be `/var/lib/samba/winbindd_privileged/`.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache-mod-auth-ntlm-winbind/+bug/1304953